# Filtering and measuring mongodb nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a document of this kind:

```
{
 _id: "123",
 arrayName: [
         { text: 'first', field: false},
         { text: 'second', field: true},
         { text: 'third', field: false}
            ]
}
```

Now I would like to my query to return the length of filtered arrayName to have only the objects where `field === false`.

I have tried many queries with `db.collection.find({})` but I always receive the entire document and in the end and it count() => to 1.

Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be? An array with 2 objects? You may be able to achieve this using aggregation, but not through querying alone.

Comment: Best would be a new array with only the objects where `field === false`. Other option just to have the amount of all the objects in arrayName with `field === false`, which in this case should be 2.

Comment: Try [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use projection operator to achieve what you want.

**Try this:**

```
db.collection.find({
    _id : givenId ,
    "arrayName.field" : false
},{
    "arrayName.$":1
},function(err,result){
   if(!err){
       len = result.arrayName.length;
       //use len however you want.
   }
});
```

`"arrayName.$":1` will select only the matched elements of the array. Then you can get the length of array with `field:false`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another user already give you the right answer for your question using the plain Mongo query. But I think it won't have much because you are using Mongo with Meteor, so here I present you another way to solve your problem by using `transform` function in `find` command:

```
Collection.find({
  // ...
}, {
  transform(doc) {
    doc.filterArrayLength = doc.arrayName.filter(obj => obj.field === false).length;

    return doc;
  }
}).fetch();
```

With this command the result will be like:

```
[
  // ...
  {
    _id: "123",
    arrayName: [
      {
        text: 'first',
        field: false
      }, {
        text: 'second',
        field: true
      }, {
        text: 'third',
        field: false
      }
    ],
    filterArrayLength: 2
  }
]
```

Comment: @RaviShankar I guess I am doing something wrong cause if I am trying to `console.log()` the returning result I am getting the entire doc from the collection, where field equals `false` but also the `true` ones as well.